# CSS styled button not appearing in IE8, works fine in other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

could someone please take a look at the following code and help me out? These are text links with CSS styled buttons with a gradient, and show up fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc. Unfortunately I also need to get this working in IE8. I did try PIE, which did not help.

Thanks for checking this out..

EDIT: Pasted wrong code

CSS

```
.home-links {
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #275da6;
  border-radius: 21px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.49) 6%, rgba(176, 192,     213, 0.29) 45%, rgba(10, 60, 125, 0.6) 87%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.49) 6%, rgba(176, 192, 213, 0.29) 45%, rgba(10, 60, 125, 0.6) 87%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.49) 6%, rgba(176, 192, 213, 0.29) 45%, rgba(10, 60, 125, 0.6) 87%);
  background-size: auto;
}

.link-text {
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
  font-family:'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;
  color: #bbd7fc;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;

 }
```

Comment: You are using ie8 for one thing.  I would try changing the name of the class.

Comment: I know, it's a client mandate. Must be fully functional in IE8. Oi.

Comment: I can not check IE. Try `display:inline-block`

Comment: Where's the gradient being declared? What is IE8 actually doing? Do you have a jsFiddle or screenshot you can include?

Comment: Also you are missing PX at the last 2 lines

Comment: @durbnpoisn You don't need to specify a unit of measure if the unit value is 0.

Comment: Did you try a positive number for `margin-top`? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231474).

Comment: @durbnpoisn 0 does not need a unit.

Comment: I was wondering how you got a gradient from that code...

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 2.x accomplished gradients in IE8 via the proprietary [Gradient Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . For instance, this is the filter rule for the default button (`.btn`) styling:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
    startColorstr='#ffffffff', 
    endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', 
    GradientType=0);
```

IE8 doesn't support rgba colors, though, so you'd have to be okay with a close approximation of the equivalent hex color.